# Typing correctness - minimising errors such as DOuble capitals

Tags: typing

I've been doing a lot of technical writing work lately, and would like to increase my writing speed by minimising errors. One error that I tend to repeat is capitalising the first two letters of a word instead of just the first letter - especially when I'm typing quickly (transcribing text from a screenshot etc).

I use the Colemak keyboard layout, am fluent at touch typing, and usually use the left shift key for capitalising. I'm writing mostly in HelpSmith, which doesn't have autocorrection features - and I prefer manually fixing my errors than having a program autocorrect in case it misunderstands what I'm writing.

Can you recommend typing techniques that can help reduce my error rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to evade using the shift key with the hand you'd type the character with. There are two shift keys for a reason. Using the shift key with the same hand results in errors as such, for me at least, and it's even worse on a membrane keyboard, which is not really comfortable to type on. Try using both shift keys and be aware of the start of any sentence so you can avoid the error; but if you're still uncomfortable, try a different keyboard.